# using oop for dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I want to refactor my code and trying to creating OOP set up for basic dataframe manipulations.
This might not make sense in a larger context but I am trying to get a better grasp on OOP.
I have tried a rename column function but it does not work on my created instance(m1).

```
df1 = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
class DataframeOperations():
    def __init__(self, df):
    self.df = df

    def rename_column(self, name:'string', name_adj:'string'):
        self.df.rename(columns = {name, name_adj}, inplace=True)
        return self.df

m1 = DataframeOperations(df1)
print(type(m1))
```

output untill this point

> <class '**main**.DataframeOperations'>

```
m1.rename_column('col1','col2')
```

I get the following error when running this function:

> TypeError: 'set' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in columns you are defining a set instead of a dictionary, try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,4]})

class DataframeOperations():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def rename_column(self, name:'string', name_adj:'string'):
        replace_dict = {name: name_adj}
        self.df.rename(columns =replace_dict , inplace=True)
        return self.df

m1 = DataframeOperations(df1)
print(type(m1))

m1.rename_column('a','b')
```

But in general and in special for OOP, what you want is that DataframeOperations inherits from pd.DataFrame:

```
class DataframeOperations(pd.DataFrame):

    def rename_column(self, name:'string', name_adj:'string'):
        replace_dict = {name: name_adj}
        self.rename(columns =replace_dict , inplace=True)
        return self

df1 = DataframeOperations({'a':[1,3,4]})
df1.rename_column('a','b')
```